# Script error message: "Could not find command in namespace"

Tags: ruby, command-line, thor

I've put this into my Foo.thor:

```
class Foo < Thor
  desc 'hello', 'prints hello'
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

Foo.start(ARGV)
```

but when executing 'thor foo:hello' i get this error message:

```
Could not find command "foo:hello" in "foo" namespace.
```

together with the output 'hello'

So that 'hello' output seems correct but the error message the line before makes me wonder, if something is wrong.

Can i get rid of that error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use **Foo.start(ARGV)** in the file. You don't need this line.

Comment: Yes, remove it even if the documentation says: "Throughout the rest of this guide, I will assume that you have a file called cli in the current directory that looks like this", and then shows a the start command. Just remove it!

Answer (score 0):

turns out, I didn't need that last line. Without it the error message disappeared!